# How can I start a process as a child of a winform in my C# program?

Tags: c#, process, mdiparent

I have a process that was written by WPF and I want to start it in my program. I used "process.start()" and its worked successfully. But now I want to start my process as a child of a form.

Comment: Process can not be a "child" of a Form, as proces is a OS Kernel citizen, but Form is your app component. Please explain what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you have a [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) usercontrol/form, and you want to display that in your [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) application?

If so, see this link: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms

Comment: Hi George,i saw that link.but that was for wpf usercontrol however i have a wpf project with several xaml files and i want to open it in one of my windows as a child of that.is there any way to do that?

Comment: From the looks of things, it seems turning your xaml files into usercontrols is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't start process as a child of a Form! Process is just another application that is running on the computer no matter if it was build in windows forms or wpf or even assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

You may mean starting new form as a child from main form?

```
using (ChildForm form = new ChildForm())
     form.ShowDialog(this); // this refers to main form object
```

Comment: Look at how you instantiate the object

Comment: @Alex you mean the `form` object? I see that it hasn't a problem - the `Form` class implements `IDisposable`, so that it can be put in a `using` statement. Or you mean the `this`? I assume that this code is in one of the methods of the main form, so that it can call `ShowDialog(IWin32Window window)` method with a reference to itself.